# Selenium Web Scrape - Why is this script returning 500k rows?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I made a script to scrape through a website to grab all product information from certain categories, but my code is returning 500 000+ rows when there are only 3000 items in that certain category.

I'm also really new to Python so any help is appreciated.

The code is attached below:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Feb  4 20:31:23 2019

@author: 
"""
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, sys
import time
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

# base set up

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
os.chdir("C:/Users/user/desktop/scripts/python")
cwd = os.getcwd()
main_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, os.pardir))
print('Main Directory:', main_dir)

chromedriver = ("C:/Users/user/desktop/scripts/python/chromedriver.exe")
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
# browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)

mainurl = "https://www.bunnings.com.au/our-range"

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(mainurl, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# script start

subcat = []
for item in soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class': 'chalkboard-menu'}):
    links = item.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        subcat.append(urljoin(mainurl, link.get("href")))
subcat

result = pd.DataFrame()
for adrs in subcat[0:1]:
#    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
#    page = requests.get(adrs, headers=headers)
#    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#    pagelink = adrs
#    adrs="https://www.bunnings.com.au/our-range/storage-cleaning/cleaning/brushware-mops/indoor-brooms"
    catProd = pd.DataFrame()
    url = adrs
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)
    browser.get(url)

    lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    match = False
    while (match == False):
        lastCount = lenOfPage
        time.sleep(3)
        lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        if lastCount == lenOfPage:
            match = True
    reached= False
    while (reached==False):
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#MoreProductsButton > span').click()
            lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
            match = True
            while (match == True):
                lastCount = lenOfPage
                time.sleep(3)
                lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
                if lastCount == lenOfPage:
                    match = True
                    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#content-layout_inside-anchor > div.search-result__content > div > div > section > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > button > div.view-more_btn_text').click()
        except:
            reached=True
# grab the items
            page = browser.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            browser.close()

        for article in soup.findAll('article', attrs={'class':'product-list__item hproduct special-order-product'}):
            for product in article.findAll('img', attrs={'class': 'photo'}):
                pName = product['alt']
                pCat = adrs
                pID = article['data-product-id']
                temp= pd.DataFrame({'proID':[pID],'Product':[pName],'Category':[pCat]})
                catProd=catProd.append(temp)
                result = result.append(catProd)
        time.sleep(3)
        result.head()

#writes to CSV
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test123123.xlsx')
result.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

The code takes something like 20 minutes to iterate through 3000~ items which is insane in my opinion but the main problem still lies that I'm getting way too many duplicates and 500 000 rows when there are only 3500 rows that I need for that certain category.

Comment: Please post a sample of what is actually returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is right here:

```
for product in article.findAll('img', attrs={'class': 'photo'}):
                pName = product['alt']
                pCat = adrs
                pID = article['data-product-id']
                temp= pd.DataFrame({'proID':[pID],'Product':[pName],'Category':[pCat]}) #<-------------- temp DataFrame
                catProd=catProd.append(temp) #<------------ temp appending into catProd dataframe
                result = result.append(catProd)  #<----------- catProd appending into result DataFrame
```

You're basically doing double appending which takes your `temp` dataframe, and appends to your `catProd` dataframe...then right after appends to your `result` dataframe. So your result dataframe is growing exponentially.

There's a couple ways you can fix this. One is move your `result = result.append(temp)` outside that loop, so the `catProd` appends to `result` after the FULL `catProd` is filled. Or, just eliminate your `catProd` all together and keep appending to your `result`.

There's also a few things I cleaned up. Ie. reset the index of the dataframe and not including the index in the excel write. I also adde explicit waits (Ie. wait for the button to show up), instead of time.sleep, which should speed it up a little bit.

Full code below. Don't forget to change `for adrs in subcat[0:1]` so that it goes thrugh the whole list. I just had it go through the first url.

Last thing is I threw in there a way to time it. Just running through the first url, 895 products and saved to csv took, `Duration: 0 Hours, 02 Minutes, 48 Seconds`

Finally, I had to comment out a few things like the os.chdir stuff so that I could run it. So don’t forget to uncomment that stuff.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, sys
import time
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import datetime

# base set up
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
#os.chdir("C:/Users/user/desktop/scripts/python")
#cwd = os.getcwd()
#main_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, os.pardir))
#print('Main Directory:', main_dir)

chromedriver = ("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
# browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)

mainurl = "https://www.bunnings.com.au/our-range"

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(mainurl, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# script start

subcat = []
for item in soup.findAll('ul', attrs={'class': 'chalkboard-menu'}):
    links = item.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        subcat.append(urljoin(mainurl, link.get("href")))
subcat

result = pd.DataFrame()
for adrs in subcat:
#    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
#    page = requests.get(adrs, headers=headers)
#    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#    pagelink = adrs
#    adrs="https://www.bunnings.com.au/our-range/storage-cleaning/cleaning/brushware-mops/indoor-brooms"
    catProd = pd.DataFrame()
    url = adrs
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)
    browser.get(url)

    lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    match = False
    while (match == False):
        lastCount = lenOfPage
        #time.sleep(3)
        lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        if lastCount == lenOfPage:
            match = True
    reached= False
    while (reached==False):
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#MoreProductsButton")))

            browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#MoreProductsButton').click()
            lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
            match = True
            while (match == True):
                lastCount = lenOfPage
                #time.sleep(3)
                lenOfPage = browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
                if lastCount == lenOfPage:
                    match = True
                    #time.sleep(3)
                    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.view-more_btn_text")))
                    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#content-layout_inside-anchor > div.search-result__content > div > div > section > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > button > div.view-more_btn_text').click()
        except:
            reached=True
# grab the items
            page = browser.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
            browser.close()

        for article in soup.findAll('article', attrs={'class':'product-list__item hproduct special-order-product'}):
            for product in article.findAll('img', attrs={'class': 'photo'}):
                pName = product['alt']
                pCat = adrs
                pID = article['data-product-id']
                temp= pd.DataFrame({'proID':[pID],'Product':[pName],'Category':[pCat]})
                #catProd=catProd.append(temp)
                result = result.append(temp)
        #time.sleep(3)
        result.head()

result.reset_index(drop=True)

#writes to CSV
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/test123123.xlsx')
result.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()

finish_time = datetime.datetime.now()
duration = finish_time - start_time

dur_list = str(duration).split(':')
hour = dur_list[0]
minutes = dur_list[1]
seconds = dur_list[2].split('.')[0]

print ('Duration: %s Hours, %s Minutes, %s Seconds' %(hour, minutes, seconds))
```